What is the difference between a passage set and a privacy set?
A passage set is used for doors that do not need to be locked, like hallways or closets, while a privacy set has a locking mechanism and is used for rooms where privacy is needed, like bedrooms or bathrooms.
I expected this to meet your needs by addressing common concerns and questions that users might have regarding these types of door hardware, thereby providing valuable and relevant information.
If you were looking for something different or have specific aspects you'd like me to focus on, please let me know!
